# Got vs made vs make

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I got her remembered everything.

I made her remember everything.

Please tell me the difference between and when to use which one thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The first sentence is grammatically incorrect. Perhaps you meant “I got her to remember everything”? I’ll assume that’s the case here.

The difference between the two sentences is that “I made her” means that you forced her to remember everything; whereas “I got her to” would mean that you encouraged or persuaded her to remember.

*To make someone do something* always implies coercion, i.e. you’re forcing them to.

*To get someone to do something* means to persuade, convince, or encourage them to.

Comment: He got himself captured, I got him captured by police are both the sentences correct

Comment: I watched in a movie subtitle, quill got himself captured why he didn't say quill made himself capture please explain a little bit